# Almacenar consulta MySQL en una variable

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Deseo guardar una consulta MySQL en una variable con PHP utilizando el Framework Symfony

```
$id_mensaje = 501;

  $result = '
   SELECT `id_carro`
   FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cliente`
   WHERE `clientes` = ' . (int)$id_mensaje  . '
   ';
    Db::getInstance()->execute($result);
```

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste la [documentación](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql)? ¿Probaste algo? ¿Tienes algún error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se vería así:

```
$result = '
   SELECT id_carro
   FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cliente
   WHERE clientes = ' . $id_mensaje;
```